# Mongrel not detecting changes in Rails classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, mongrel, mongrel-cluster

I have a Rails app installed on a Slicehost server running Apache 2 and Ubuntu LTC 10.04. Things have worked beautifully up until now: I edit a file, do a quick `mongrel_rails cluster::restart`, and the changes are reflected in production. However, suddenly this process has broken down.

For example, I have a class called `Master` located in `/lib/master.rb`. I added a new method to this class that simply runs `puts "it works!"`, then restarted the mongrel cluster. Looking at the production logs, the server throws an error and thinks this method doesn't exist. When I go to the console using `ruby script/console production`, however, I can use this new method perfectly. I even tried deleting the file containing entire `Master` class. Once again, the production thought it was still there, but the production console correctly recognized it was missing.

Any ideas? How can the production environment detect a class that doesn't even exist anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny, I spend 2 hours debugging this, then post to StackOverflow and figure it out in 20 minutes.

The problem is that I needed to also restart my background jobs as well. They were running the old version of the classes stored in /lib. It's interesting that this problem has never snagged me before.